# compare database column values in mysql with another String in java

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

I have a database with the following layout

```
databasename:macfast
table name:users

columns

  id,
  user_name,
  password,
  fullName
```

I want to retrieve all the values from the column user_name and check  each values with another one string which is already retrieved from a `TEXTFIELD`.But I can't(`NullpointerException`). Please help me.

```
  public void deleteFclty() {

             PreparedStatement stmt = null;
             ResultSet rs = null;
             String username=removeText.getText();




     String qry = "SELECT user_name From users ";
    try {
        stmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(qry);


     rs =  stmt.executeQuery();

     while (rs.next()) {
           String check=(rs.getString("user_name"));

           System.out.println(check);


           if(check.equals(username)){

                Util.showErrorMessageDialog("EQUAL");

           }else{

                     Util.showErrorMessageDialog("NOT EQUAL");
   }
     }
}catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RemoveFaculty.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line does the `NullPointerException` occur?

Comment: no value specified for parameter 1....so null point exeption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the prepared statement (you don't put id into statement, which should be there instead of question mark).

Also I would recommend to do condition as "username.equals(check)", that can prevent null pointer exception.

Comment: i need only the column (user_name) values....How can i retrieve that?Only i have one input is String prepared from textfield.thats my entered username.My plan is to check that with the corresponding column values and if the entered value is present at the databse....so on....so please make a corresponding preparedStatement for me

Comment: So you should have select just like this: "SELECT user_name From users" and go through values, if you want to do it like this. Otherwise I would recommend this statement "SELECT count(user_name) as cnt From users where user_name = ?" and then call stmt.setString(username). rs.getInt("cnt") shoud return how many usernames are in the database then. (If larger than zero, then it exists).

Comment: Now problem solved sir.But a new challenge......how can i check textfields manually entered username present at the database or not...thats my new challenge.please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT user_name From users where id=?"
```

This query has a parameter and you're not setting any value to it. Use [`PreparedStatement#setInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) or similar to set it, e.g.:

```
stmt.setInt(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question in comment below:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList();
while (rs.next()) {
    values.add(0,rs.getString(<>))
}
// here do whatever you want to do...
// for example
for ( String value: values )
{
    // check if value == TEXTFIELD
    // if true then do something..
    // else don't do anything
}
```

Comment: I think other people are here to help you out. Then only possibility is your error. You should edit your question and please indicate that on which line Exception is coming.

Comment: sir pblm solved...please check my edited code....it checks each value and give outputs..eavery time dialog boxes pop ups...i want to check the text field vaue is in database or not....how can i do that?suggest

Comment: how can i check textfields manually entered username present at the database or not...thats my new challenge.please help me

Comment: Not getting what you mean exactly by '.i want to check the text field vaue is in database or not. ' .. Please explain

Comment: In my application contains a textfield.i would extract that value into a string.Then how can i check that string with the database column values.In my example String check contains many database values but 

    check.equals(username) pop up dialog boxes each time

Comment: i mean suppose i am entering saranya into the textfield...expecting the SUCCESS dialog box when  the database column containing saranya ...not containing pop up an ERROR dialog box...got it?

Comment: can i use arraylist for that?

Comment: not working....it works but while loop creates diffrent sets of output....i want only one set

Comment: What is `rs.getString(<>)`?? This won't compile in Java. Also why copy the ResultSet to a List to begin with? Just check from the ResultSet directly.

Comment: You are right... Just jotted these lines so that original person asking the question can have some ideas that how to go about that... and <> comes from unix conventions where.. it has to be replaced using appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with PreparedStatement as you are using Question mark ? in your query for that you have to set the Id value.

```
 String qry = "SELECT user_name From users where id=?";
 stmt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(qry);
 stmt.setInt(1,1001);
 rs =  stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: how can i check textfields manually entered username present at the database or not...thats my new challenge.please help me

Comment: @SaranyaSaru SO is not a forum. If you have another question, post it in a separate question.